# mobile chrome shows strange background image when using background-attachment fixed on every reload

Tags: css, mobile-chrome

In my [site](https://www.monsoonmalabar.com/) I used background image like,

```css
.bod {
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="bod" style="background: url(http://www.monsoonmalabar.com/assets/jum1-d81369e264bcff56f61eb494888a3f3960c0108ec43c421b253f80c414bf506d.jpg) no-repeat fixed;">
```

Now in mobile chrome I get a strange stretched image which slightly changes its look on every reload.

Comment: it is possible that on desktop the image looks good because it's cropped for desktop resolutions. for mobile either change the proportions of the container or change background-size to 'contain'

Comment: If I resized browser to mobile dimension, it works well on pc browser, also note it works well on android firefox. It sometime shows correct image in mobile chrome also, but sometimes misbehaves

Comment: Any fix for this problem?